# Delete row data (do not remove row) if a special character ("¤") is present anywhere in the row

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

I'm trying to create a macro or VBA code that checks the spreadsheet for this symbol: ¤. If it find this value, it needs to make the data in the row into blanks, eg. it shouldn't remove the row entirely.

I'm using Excel2010 for this, and any help would be much appreciated.

Tried editing the following code I've found, but not having any luck, with the range search or how to leave a cell blank instead of deleting the row.

```
    Sub Deletesymbol()
        Dim Firstrow As Long
        Dim Lastrow As Long
        Dim Lrow As Long
        Dim CalcMode As Long
        Dim ViewMode As Long

        With Application
            CalcMode = .Calculation
            .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
            .ScreenUpdating = False
        End With

        With ActiveSheet

        .Select


        ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
        ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView

        .DisplayPageBreaks = False


        Firstrow = .UsedRange.Cells(1).Row
        Lastrow = .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row


        For Lrow = Lastrow To Firstrow Step -1


            With .Range("A:BJ")

                If Not IsError(.Value) Then

                    If .Value = "¤" Then **.EntireRow.Delete**

                End If

            End With

        Next Lrow

    End With

    ActiveWindow.View = ViewMode
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: And what have you tried already?

Comment: Sorry about that, added code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
Sub rowKiller()
    Dim rng As Range, r As Range
    Set rng = Nothing
    For Each r In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells.SpecialCells(2)
        If InStr(1, r.Value, Chr(164)) > 0 Then
            If rng Is Nothing Then
                Set rng = r
            Else
                Set rng = Union(rng, r)
            End If
        End If
    Next r

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        rng.EntireRow.Clear
    End If
End Sub
```

This should be pretty quick since at most ***1*** `Clear` is performed.
*I am assuming that the `CHAR(164)'s` are in constants rather than formulas.*

Comment: That they are, and this code does the trick perfectly. Thank you very much :)

Comment: In a worse case scenario, where there is "¤" in every cell of the row, the code is about 16K slower than it could be. Checking every cell is a bit time & processor waste.

Comment: @Vityata  I agree completely!! ...................an even **"worser"** case would be if EVERY CELL on the worksheet contained a `CHAR(164)`

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution that should work for you:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim symbol          As String:      symbol = Chr(164)
    Dim myRow           As Range
    Dim myCell          As Range
    Dim rowToDelete     As Range

    For Each myRow In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells.Rows
        Set myCell = myRow.Find(symbol)
        If Not myCell Is Nothing Then
            If rowToDelete Is Nothing Then
                Set rowToDelete = myRow
            Else
                Set rowToDelete = Union(rowToDelete, myRow)
            End If
        End If
        Set myCell = Nothing
    Next myRow

    If Not rowToDelete Is Nothing Then
        'you may use rowToDelete.Select to see what would be cleared
        rowToDelete.EntireRow.Clear   '.ClearContents is also possible
    End If

End Sub
```

This is what it does:

- It loops through all the rows in a given Range. In your code you are using `UsedRange`, thus you can write `UsedRange.Rows` instead of `Range("A1:E10").Rows`.
- It tries to set `myCell` to a cell, which contains the `Chr(164)` symbol
- If it exists, it adds the row to the Range `rowToDelete`
- At the end, it clears the whole range `rowToDelete`. If you do not want to remove the style, write `.ClearContents` instead of `.Clear`.

Comment: @Vitaya, `If myCell Is Nothing Then` should be `If Not myCell Is Nothing Then`. And then I always adopted such loops with the check on found cell address not to match first found cell and avoid an endless loop when `Find()` method wraps back to first cell found

Comment: @DisplayName - `If Not myCell is Nothing` is correct, thanks.

Comment: @DisplayName - can you give a scenario, where `Find()` goes into an endless loop?

Comment: actually I intended `FindNext()` which is not what you're using... I never used `Find()` _per se_ in a loop, and _nulling_ it at every iteration: sooner or later I will try it and see the outcome

Answer (score 1):

Two working solutions:

1. Checks for special character if you know where to expect it and clears specified row

   ```
   Sub SearchForChar()

   Dim maxRow As Long
   Dim ws As Worksheet

   Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Replace Sheet1 with your worksheet name

   maxRow = ws.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

   For i = 1 To maxRow
       If ws.Range("A" & i).Value Like "*¤*" Then 'Replace A where you expect ¤ to be
           ws.Range("A" & i).EntireRow.Value = "" 'sets value of whole row to null
       End If
   Next i

   End Sub
   ```
2. Checks each cell in whole worksheets and clears whole row if found
       Sub SearchForChar()

   ```
   'Check each cell in the whole worksheet for ¤ and removes whole row if it finds it.
   Dim ws As Worksheet

   Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Replace Sheet1 with your worksheet name

   For Each cell In ws.Cells
       If cell.Value Like "*¤*" Then
           cell.EntireRow.Value = ""
       End If
   Next cell

   End Sub
   ```

Edit:

3. As requested in comment you can use something like this

   ```
   Sub SearchForChar()        
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   'Check each cell in the whole worksheet for ¤ and removes whole row    if it finds it.
   Dim ws As Worksheet
   Dim rng as Range
   Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Replace Sheet1 with your worksheet name 
   For Each rng In ws.Range("A5:B1000")
       If rng.Value Like "*¤*" Then
             rng.EntireRow.Value = ""
       End If
   Next rng    
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   End Sub
   ```

Comment: I tried your second suggestion, and it did work, however since it searches the whole workbook, Excel kinda crashed. 
Trying your first suggestion, if I want to check A5:BA1000, do I change this line? If ws.Range("A" & i).Value Like "*¤*"  to "A5:BA100"?

Comment: Sorry, It really should be `For Each rng In ws.Range("A5:B1000")
Thanks

Comment: Don't you think that if you check every cell for a given value then your code might get 16K times slower?

Comment: @Vityata - Of course it will! That's why I posted 3 different solutions to the questions so the appropriate can be used. I just showed the way how this can be resolved and it's up to the asking person to choose correct answer to their queries.

Comment: Well, solutions 2 and 3 are still checking cell by cell and the 1. one is with preselected column.

Comment: What's your point? I feel this is an idle conversation going on here...

Answer (score 1):

if you want to remove the character from any cell *containing* it, then just use Replace() method with `lookAt:=xlPart` parameter:

```
Sub main()
    With Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("A:BJ"))
        .Replace what:=Chr(164), lookAt:=xlPart, Replacement:=""
    End With
End Sub
```

if you want to clear the cells whose content exactly *matches* that character, then still use Replace() method but with `lookAt:=xlWhole` parameter:

```
Sub main()
    With Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("A:BJ"))
        .Replace what:=Chr(164), lookAt:=xlWhole, Replacement:=""
    End With
End Sub
```

if you want to clear the content of a whole row where at least one cell contains that character, then use `Find()` function within a loop

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim found As Range, cellsToClear As Range
    Dim firstAddress As String

    With Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("A:BJ"))
        Set found = .Find(what:=Chr(164), lookAt:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not found Is Nothing Then
            Set cellsToClear = .Offset(, .Columns.Count).Resize(1, 1)
            firstAddress = found.Address
            Do
                Set cellsToClear = Union(cellsToClear, found)
                Set found = .FindNext(found)
            Loop While found.Address <> firstAddress
            Intersect(cellsToClear, Range("A:BJ")).entireRow.ClearContents 'clear the content of found cells entire row
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @FoolzRailer, should the last one be your case, then this solution is quite fast since it 1) loops through cells containing the character only (and not through all the cells of the specified range) 2) makes a one-shot cell content clearing

Answer (score 1):

Here an alternative with Find:

```
Sub RowKiller()

Dim rng As Range

Do While True

    Set rng = Cells.Find(What:="¤", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
        , SearchFormat:=False)
    If rng Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    rng.EntireRow.Delete
Loop

End Sub
```